# package javax.servlet does not exist - ubuntu, tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, ubuntu, classpath

echo $CLASSPATH

```
  /home/user/tomcat/lib/server-api.jar
```

echo $JAVA_HOME

```
  .:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
```

but when I try to compile .java which are in class folder

```
  javac  *.java
```

I get

```
  HelloServlet.java:2: package javax.servlet does not exist
```

and additional 5 similar errors.

I get no errors when

```
  javac -cp /home/user/tomcat/lib/servlet-api.jar *.java
```

Why is that? What should I change to make it work without -cp /path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your classpath doesn't actually contain **servlet-api.jar**.  The echo of CLASSPATH shows that it has server-api.jar in the path, but not servlet-api.jar.  Try adding servlet-api.jar to your CLASSPATH definition and see if it works then.

Comment: Yes, my mistake, thank you for pointing this out. Nevertheless adjustment of the classpath didn't make any change. echo $CLASSPATH
/home/user/tomcat/lib/servlet-api.jar and still I get the same errors.

Comment: Hmmm, I was hoping it was an easy fix. Have you tried executing javac with the `-verbose` option to see what the classpath is set to?  Then you could compare differences in the classpath between using `-cp` and `$CLASSPATH`.  `javac -verbose *.java`

Comment: I have found the solution. I had set the paths in this file: ~/.bashrc. This is a mistake, has no effect. I deleted the paths from that file and I have placed them here: /etc/environment and it works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks Mike for posting I didn't know that this can be checked with -verbose. Great stuff, thanks!

Comment: Well, I have the [same issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15082890/compiling-a-servlet-in-ubuntu-returns-errors#comment21213913_15082890) except with a little change that I am not changing the classpath permanently. Help with that ? @MikeBockus

Answer (score -1):

you are gettig this error because **servlet-api.jar** file is not present in your path which you have written . Try to download **servlet-api.jar** file from this link  http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadservletapijar.htm
and extract the zip file in the download folder and then move **servlet-api.jar** to /var/lib/tomcat8/lib/ folder .

And for complie java file first go to "src" folder in your project by terminal and write command..

**sudo javac -d ../classes/ *.java -cp /var/lib/tomcat8/lib/servlet-api.jar**